# How to transmit more than 2048 chars to *.sh script in ksh?

Tags: shell, ksh

I need to transmit a parameter which consists more than 2048 chars to ksh script. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ your_script your...really...long...parameter
```

Where `your_script` consists of:

```
#!/bin/ksh
do_something_with "$1"
```

or

```
$ command_with_large_output | your_script
```

Where `your_script` consists of:

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read -r line
do
    do_something_with "$line"
done
```

Other combinations are possible.